# How can I stop my two year old from taking off his diaper in bed?

Tags: toddler, sleep, diaper

Recently, my two-year-old son has been taking off his diaper at nap time. It's usually full and dirty and makes a big mess. He has managed to do it while wearing all types of pants (even overalls). This only happens at nap time. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: It sounds like he's ready for toilet training! Though inconvenient and messy, this isn't something I would discourage.

Comment: If his diaper/nappy is full, why not change it? That way he can sleep better without getting rash/burns, especially when teething.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson I am sure Yedida would change her son and isn't trying to prolong the amount of time he is in a dirty diaper, just trying to contain the mess until she is aware of it to deal with it.

Comment: My twins are purposely pushing little poops out and smearing it everywhere. I am looking for ways to keep diapers on them so they can't do this. If they pooped I would change them. One is in the process of potty training and one isn't interested. I am trying to end the "fun game" that they have discovered. I have tried bribing; getting mad; reasoning; explaining; cuddling; putting on potty before bed; etc. They think taking a diaper off and pooping is hilarious.

Comment: @Dionne, I use two-part reusable nappies with my son, a bamboo nappy with an outer wrapper. Some of our wrappers have popper studs to hold them closed, he can't get those open (whereas the velcro ones we have he can). You can just use the outer wrapper over a disposable nappy.

Comment: I've tried everything, even duct tape. I'm going crazy.

Comment: Two words: Toilet training. The child is aware that the full diaper is uncomfortable and wants to be rid of it. Now is a golden moment when the toilet training will be easy. Take it, and you will both enjoy freedom from diapers in short order.

Answer (score 20):

Take a one-piece pajama, the sort with long arms and legs, but without feet, that has a zipper running from one leg to the top, and put it on backwards.  It's completely tamper-proof, easy to "service", and ought to be equally comfortable.

We have tried many of the other suggestions (diaper backwards, onesie, onesie plus some kind of trousers, "duck" tape, sleeping bag), but they were all found out after a short while.  If he gets the backwards pajamas off, he'll be ready to join a circus.

Comment: This was genius.  WE actually cut feet off a pair as we didn't have any of that type without feet.  Thank you so much for the help!!!

Comment: Yeah, we ended up cutting the feet off a few as well, as it is more useful that way.  Also, it allows the pajamas to be used longer, as the child grows.

Comment: I have heard this suggestion from many, many parents.  Never had to use it, but one of those things I file away in case I do!

Comment: Enterprising parents with sewing skills could attach velcro and/or button fasteners to those cut off feet so that they can still be used as hand-me-downs!

Comment: Just be aware a thin enough child can easily get out of these.  I sadly had one that could climb right through the neck hole.  In the odd time that didn't work, she could pull her hands inside, remove the diaper & manage to pull that out through the neck hole.  I had high hopes when I read this idea (they even sell pjs already made this way) and it really didn't even work for one day.

Comment: OMG. @threetimes, our children must be long lost twins. My daughter can also get out of the backward pajamas via the neck, and has managed to get her diaper off and out of the jammies as well, like magic.  Based on how fast she can get over fences (instantly) I think she can levitate too. I’m trying to find a gypsy circus that will take her. (Kidding!)

Answer (score 14):

Duct Tape (aka Duck Tape). We actually had to do that a couple times. Of course be sure you check on your son frequently, because he may have an aversion to having the stinky diaper on - he may be developing a diaper rash. Also be sure the tape doesn't get on his skin as it will probably irritate his skin.

Our son got through it after a while and we didn't use the tape for long.

Comment: Great idea.  We use the white medical tape sometimes for diaper fasteners with inadequate adhesive.  Not as strong as duct tape, but not as bad for your child's skin either if it accidentally gets on.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like he's trying to tell his parents something - namely, that his diaper needs to be changed. Forcing the kid to wear the diaper anyway isn't cool, don'tchathink?

Comment: @Ernie: Totally, which is why I said check on the kid frequently and don't leave them in a soiled diaper. The thing is it is better to have them in a soiled diaper then to have them remove the diaper and cover their body with poop. Either way they will be in poop for how ever much time it takes you to notice they need changed. The duck tape just keeps the poop and diaper in a smaller area.

Comment: While it may be better not to have the child covered in poop, there is a way to teach them to ask for help instead.  Ernie is absolutely right but particularly, he is probably saying not only that he is dirty but that perhaps it is time to toilet train.

Comment: @balancedmama: I'm not suggesting leaving your child duck taped into a soiled diaper. Sure, potty train them, by all means. But with our son he had no interest in potty training at the time, he just started taking his diaper off if he got stinky while in the crib, which is what I thought Yedida was asking about. Duck Tape is not an alternative to potty training or changing diapers. It just contains the mess, same as a diaper. You wouldn't suggest putting your child to bed without a diaper on before they were potty trained would you?

Comment: @JimMcKeeth, I wouldn't expect my child to lie in the dirty diaper either.  I am suggesting teaching him how to ask for help - he is two.  Barring some sort of disability he should be able to learn he can go to mom or dad and say, "diaper dirty."  Allowing him to get up to use the toilet if it occurs to him to do so before spoiling his diaper in the first place is also a good plan.  Would you want some one to force you to lay in your own mess?

Comment: Nobody suggested to force them to lie in their own mess. This is simply a way to keep the child to spread their mess all over their bed and body.

Answer (score 10):

1. He is taking the diaper off because he is uncomfortable.  BIG SIGNAL that is time to potty train and a really good reason not to force him to stay in it.  How well do you sleep if you are uncomfortable anyway?
2. Ask him to sit on the potty about 15 minutes before naptime.  While he sits, read stories, play clapping games, sing songs etc so that it is fun to be there.  He may not poop, but he might and he'll most likely at least pee if he is relaxed enough.  Don't sit so long waiting that he becomes uncomfortable, but at least give him the chance to "get it out" before nap so that he isn't laying in a mess during nap.  This may help temendously with potty training as well anyway.  Leave enough time to still do your regular nap time routine after the potty part.
3. Put him in pull ups (during naps only, regular pants the rest of the time so he can still feel the wetness) and let him get up during nap to use the potty if he "feels the need".  Let him know he should come get you.  That way you can help clean him up without a huge mess if he is waking up dirty.  I know it means an interruption to nap and that sucks, but if he gets the hang of potty training relatively quickly this will only go on for a month or two.
4. You may be concerned he will begin to use this as an excuse not to take a nap and the reality is that MIGHT happen, if it does you can cross that bridge when it comes.  Even if you waited, this issue will arise eventually anyway. In a classroom of 20 "2's" we always had 1 or 2 kids for whom this became an issue (true in the threes as well).  It is just one of the realities of toddlerhood some parents must find a way to deal with.  Once he is fully potty trained you can say things like, "you should only need to get up to go potty once". . .
5. Expect him to sleep later and alter his sleep schedule if needed to help avoid bowel movements during sleep.

It is a tough transition that affects sleep, your entire schedule really and means messes and accidents for awhile, but think about this: once you bite the bullet and make the transition, you won't be buying diapers anymore, (although you'll still be lugging around a big bag of kid stuff), having to find places to stop and change the diaper will be in the past and although you will still need to find potties, you can plan ahead by asking him to go when you ARE near a potty.  This will reduce accidents, rushing around in a panic, and is an introduction to teaching him about "planning ahead" for other things in life too.

For the actual potty training - there are LOTS of ways to go about doing it.  You are even lucky enough to have him telling you he wants to potty train when it is summer and he can safely and comfortably play naked at times (immediate understanding of the "prefeeling" before peeing and the other one, because he will see it happen)  A quick search will give you lots of options for techniques and I believe there are a number of questions about potty training right here on stack exchange.

I personally think the best way is to get them comfortable with the toilet (its sounds, sitting on one, washing hands after . . .) by spending time in the bathroom together singing songs, play hand clapping games, I used to sing to my 2's class, "tinkle tinkle in the potty, get that stuff out of your body, it is so much better for you, to use the potty for your pee pee and your poo, tinkle tinkle in the potty. . . It always got a laugh.

I would also suggest you spend this time in the bathroom (and out) reading books about going potty.  There is a book with Elmo with buttons (that make noises like the toilet flushing and water running in the sink) that talks about buying "big boy pants" and the whole process as well as an episode that can be purchased all about potty training where [Elmo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000G0O5F0) helps (I think it's baby bear's little sister if I remember correctly) with her potty training and we meet Elmo's dad etc.  There is even a song called "accidents happen".  There is also "no more diapers for ducky" (another book) and a set of books that is something like "the potty book for boys" and "the potty book for girls" that are all really good (plus numerous others)

Any time he goes poop in the diaper, have him watch you roll the poop off the diaper and into the toilet while you talk about how poop and pee belong in the toilet and then flush it together.  I am not a fan of "rewards" or "punishments" there are natural rewards like, not feeling "icky" and the reward of the independence that comes with being diaper free and becoming a "big boy" that are likely to work with your kid (simply talk about them), but rewards work really well for lots of kids too.

Good Luck!

Comment: Link is to a synopsis of the video on amazon.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry, I couldn't help laughing out loud :-)  Been there, done that, but the pants thing has always worked for us.  Sometimes easier said than done, but you can try moving nap time so he can finish it with a clean diaper, or maybe try a heavier duty/more absorbent brand.  It sounds like he's just uncomfortable.

Answer (score 8):

I put the diaper on backwards AND used duct tape with my daughter.  We started potty training IMMEDIATELY when she started peeling off her diaper.

My son? He could care less about taking off his diaper. He wants to try to climb up the drapes.

Answer (score 4):

I find that putting a Onesie and overalls on our 20-month-old son usually does the trick.  Overalls over the diaper still allows access from the top. But with the combination of the two, he'll have to work his way from the top and bottom.

We actually used a Onesies, then pants, then another Onsie with overalls on top (it was during winter). He gave up after that.

Answer (score 4):

We used the sleeping bag type outfits - you know, the ones with holes for arms and head. These not only removed any possibility of removing the nappy, but also stopped our kids waking up because the had kicked their covers off, and stopped them getting out of bed at 4 in the morning and wandering!

(they learned to climb out of a cot at a very early age, so this was essential, the little monkeys)

Comment: +1 for the sleeping bag, but my "little monkey" can climb and walk around even when he's in it! I'm wondering whether he's got some levitation trick going. (Where's Charles Xavier when you need him?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting the diaper on backwards which may only work for a little while.

Answer (score 1):

> Recently, my two-year-old son has been taking off his diaper at nap time. ***It's usually full and dirty and makes a big mess.***

If the diaper is terribly full and dirty why exactly do you want him to keep on wearing it? It might be utterly uncomfortable/wet, that might be the reason that he is trying to take it off!

My advice is to not let him continue wearing a diaper which is so full and dirty. Before he starts becoming uncomfortable, simply change the diaper.

Observe what happens when he wears a clean and fresh diaper. Does he still try to pull it off? If yes, then duct-tape may be the solution. If not, then have mercy on him and change the diaper.

Making him unable to take his dirty diaper off by tape is cruelty IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Masking tape has been working pretty well for our daughter with the same issue (any time, day or night).  We have to wrap it all the way around her waist so she doesn't take it off.  I'm glad she's almost ready for toilet training.  Good luck!